# jekyll auto compile all markdown files

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I have multiple git repos that just contain markdown files. I want these to be separate and maintained purely as markdown.

Then I am pulling these in as submodules to my github pages repo and I want to compile them to HTML with a layout I specify.

I have tried various things like

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "my-submodule1"
    values:
      layout: "my-submodule1-layout"
```

in my _config.yml (using jekyll serve)

However, these files never get compiled to HTML, just copied in as markdown files. It seems I am forced to include jekyll config stuff at the top of the markdown files to get them compiled.

Is it possible to have markdown files with no jekyll config in them compiled to html with a layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing or not, that is the question ?

File **with** a [front matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) --> jekyll processing

File **without** front matter = [static file](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/) --> just copied

The minimal front matter is :

```
---
---
```

Comment: Thanks, that minimum does cause the markdown files to be processed by jekyll. Unless someone else comes along with a better solution i'll figure out that best way to include this and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
---
layout: null
---

Markdown content
```

But I'm not sure that's what you need to achieve what you want.

Comment: `layout: null` will override the default configuration set in `_config.yml`.

Comment: Good point @DavidJacquel! I've completely missed that! Should I remove the answer?